# How can I fix "Error Parsing DDL" on create schema in MySql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When simply creating a new schema in MySql workbench using the shortcut button I get an error message after executing the default query "Error Parsing DDL for new_schema". I recently installed the latest versions of MySql workbench / server (8.0.16).

I have tried changing the charset/collation from the default to utf8 and still am getting the error "There was an error while parsing the DDL retrieved from the server.".

I get the usual prompt to review sql before it is applied to database

```
CREATE SCHEMA `new_schema` ;
```

Yet once I click apply I get the error message and the following statement in the editor..

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DATABASE `new_schema` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */$$
```

Along with the final DEFAULT(before ENCRYPTION) underlined in red stating "not valid at this position for this server version, expecting CHARSET,CHAR,COLLATE".

I have not used workbench in some time and had to re-install because I could not get the server to start but I used to be able to create schemas easily without any errors.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this really MySQL Workbench 8.0.16? Sounds like you have an older version, which doesn't understand the ENCRYPTION part. What happens when you execute this statement? I guess that succeeds. So it's mostly an issue of WB reporting something wrong.

Comment: @MikeLischke Yes i just downloaded and installed the most recent version yesterday. Terminal command mysql -V returns version 8.0.16 confirmed. It does succeed and create the schema. Its mainly just an annoyance so far isn't actually affecting the build or any queries done via ORM in any projects. Ah maybe I'll try fresh install or a previous version like 8.0.13 which I believe I had previous.